# Basics: $x \in B$. Do we mean(here)that all the supposed elements belong to set $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When we say that $x\in B$ do we mean that all the supposed elements belong to set B?

Like let $B=\{a,b,c,d\}$.

When we say $x\in B$, does that mean that we're supposing $a, b, c$, and $d$ as x?

And let's say, $y \in A \cup B$. Does this mean that all the elements belonging to $A \cup B$ are elements of group $y$?

You can skip all that. what I really mean to ask is:

> does $x$ and $y$ represent each element of the given set (like in set-builder form) or are they sets themselves? (which i'm positively sure it's not, but doubt it, anyway.Yeah, 'sure' and doubt)

Comment: $B=\{....\}$ means that the members of $B$ are all those, and only those things named or described within the brackets. So if $B=\{a,b,c,d\}$ then $x\in B$ means $(x=a$ or  $x=b$ or $x=c$ or $x=d).$... And if it happens that $a$ turns out to be equal to $d$ then $\{a,b,c,d\}=\{a,b,c\}=\{c,d,b\}.$ That is, specifying the members of a set is not the same thing as specifying a $sequence.$ It is just a statement of what is or is not a member , and no more. (Some students get confused about that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the notation $\in$ means that whatever in front of this sign is an element instead of a set. If you want some set there use $\subset$ instead.

Here $x$ or $y\in B$ means that it could represent any element in $B$.

For instance, if $B=\mathcal{R}$ and $x=\sqrt2$, $x$ is in $B$. in other words,

$x\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

When we say $x \in B$ we mean that $x$ is an element of the set $B$.

Let's make an example: $2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $2$ is an integer and $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}$, because $\sqrt{2}$ is not an integer.

$x \in A \cup B$ means that either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.

Example: $-2 \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{-2,-4,-6,...\}$ because $-2 \in \{-2,-4,-6,..\}$ even if $-2 \notin \mathbb{N}$. At the same time $-1 \notin \mathbb{N} \cup \{-2,-4,-6,...\}$ because it doesn't belong to any of the two sets.

$x \in A \cap B$ means that $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.

Example: $6 \in \{2,4,6,8,...\} \cap \{3,6,9,12,15,...\}$ because $6 \in \{2,4,6,8,...\}$ and $6 \in \{3,6,9,12,15,...\}$, but $4 \notin \{2,4,6,8,...\} \cap \{3,6,9,12,15,...\}$ since $4 \notin \{3,6,9,12,15,...\}$